# Button placed on google map disappear after adding constraints Xcode ios Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, button, constraints

I am making an iOS app and I am having trouble setting up constraints on my UIButton (which is placed on a google map). I want the button to be placed at the bottom center of my google map. When I run the app on my phone I can see the button. But as soon as I apply the constraint on my button, it disappears from the screen. Constraint added through the "add new constraint" button at the bottom.

[image]

I have no idea why these constraints are not being added. I have also tried solving this problem with code.

```
self.takePictureBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

self.takePictureBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: self.mapView.frame.size.height - 60).isActive = true
```

Even the code above doesn't work. Is there any other simple way of adding constraints?

Comment: What is the superview of the button?

Comment: the superview of the button is a view which is placed on google maps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code, you have to add this line before your add constraints
takePictureBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Btw, you need to provide more information about design structure so that we can help you.